# Función en JS que devuelva

Tags: javascript

Necesito una función que recibe 2 parámetros, un array con los arrays de ingresos de varios días, y el otro con la cantidad mínima de personas que asistieron esos días en promedio. Poder recorrerlo y en base a eso devolver true o false diciendo que días si se abrió y que días no se abrió.
Es muy similar a la función **seAbre** que ya tengo creada, pero lee solamente un día, acá necesito que lea varios días.

Por ejemplo para representar 3 días de la semana y con un mínimo de 2 personas sería de la siguiente manera:

```
aperturas([ingresosDelLunes, ingresosDelMartes, ingresosDelMiercoles], 2)
[true, false, false]
```

La variable "ingresosDelDía" lee a que hora llegaron las personas ese día, para saber si fueron puntuales o no.

Ejemplo: 2 personas llegaron tarde (10 y 3 minutos), una puntual y una 5 minutos antes, queda  así:

```
var ingresosDelLunes = [10, -5, 3, 0];
```

En el siguiente fragmento de código necesito arreglar la función **aperturas** que me devuelve todo falso.

```
function seAbre(arr, limite){
var cantidad = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                if (arr[i] <= 0){
                    cantidad = cantidad + 1;
                }
            }
            if (cantidad >= limite) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
}
function aperturas(seAbre, limite){
    var result = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < seAbre.length; i++){
                if (seAbre[i].length <= limite) { 
                    result[i]=true;}
                 else {
                    result[i]=false;
                }}
    return result; }
```

Comment: Centrate en explicar el problema para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte, explica cual es la intención de tu algoritmo.
Aún no le encuentro sentido, tienes un arreglo con los tiempos de llegada de cada día de algun número de personas, si el tiempo excede un máximo de tiempo, el día se cierra?

Comment: Creo que no había sido claro Andres, ahí trate de detallar mi necesidad y el problema que estoy teniendo, muchas gracias por la sugerencia. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo muy bien cómo quieres que funcione, solo he entendido que necesitas un vector de booleanos como resultado. Te explico cómo hacerlo. En vez de hacer un `return true` o `return false` (instrucción que hará que tu función termine en ese punto), creamos un vector de booleanos y le asignamos los valores correspondientes en la posición que toque en esa iteración del bucle. Así:

```
function aperturas(arr, limite){
var cantidad = 1;
    var results = [false, false, false];
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                if (arr[i] <= 2){
                    cantidad = cantidad + 1;
                }
                if (cantidad > limite) {
                results[i]=true;
                }
                 else {
                    results[i]=false;
                }
            }

    return results;
}
```

De esta forma la salida que te da para esta entrada `aperturas([4, 2, 3], 2)` es `[false,false,false]`

Tendrás que ver la condición para que sea true o false, ya que no entiendo cómo quieres que funcione exactamente. Aquí te muestro cómo hacerlo para retornar un vector de booleanos.

Espero que te sirva.

Enlace al [test 1](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FJ7LJXBFHXUC).

### Editado

Según tu condición de "se abre" / "no se abre", si un día ha habido más de x clientes debe retornar `true`. Así quedaría tu función `aperturas`:

```
function aperturas(arr, limite){
    var result = [false, false, false];
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                /* arr[i].length: Cantidad de clientes de cada dia */
                if (arr[i].length > limite) { 
                    result[i]=true;
                }
                 else {
                    result[i]=false;
                }
            }

    return result;
}
```

Enlace al [test2](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FJ02CYNKBTN6).

Comment: He editado mi respuesta con una nueva versión. Dime si es lo que necesitabas. Saludos

Comment: Hola Dani y @TioPalta. Intentad ir borrando los comentarios que estén obsoletos para no llenar la publicacion. Si quereis puedo crearos un chat para que hableis de esta respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: Dani, prácticamente ya esta, pero vi en tu comentario que pusiste que para que de **true** tiene que haber 2 o + alumnos Y que entre llegadas puntuales y tarde sea mayor a 0, puede ser que eso no lo este validando?

Por ejemplo me esta devolviendo esto (el primer valor es lo de nuestro función, el segundo el correcto):

aperturas([[0, 0, 3, 0], [1, 2, 4, 5], [0, 0, -1]], 3)
[ true, true, false ] deepEqual [ true, false, true ]

aperturas([[0, 0, -3, 0], [1, 2, 4, 5], [0, 0, -1]], 4) 
[ false, false, false ] deepEqual [ true, false, false ]

Comment: Por favor, explica claramente el funcionamiento que tiene que tener y que condicion tiene que cumplirse para cada dia para que se devuelva true o false. Si algún moderador puede habilitarnos un chat, lo agradecería